# Query multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables `Manager`, `Lead`, `Trainee` and the way they are related through a `Relation` table.

Attached image depicts the tables with saple rows and columns :

[image]

I need to get the `Lead` name and `Trainee` name for a given `Manger.Id`.

I have got the parameter name from the below query:

```
select 
    L.Name
from 
    Lead L, Manager M, Relation R 
where 
    R.PrimaryId = M.Id 
    and R.SecondaryId = L.Id 
    and M.Id = 'M101';
```

How do I get the trainee name apart from the lead name?

Comment: What do you want to achieve because according to your question you simply could just `select Name from Trainee`

Comment: @itwasntme I need to get the Lead name and Trainee name for a given Manger.Id.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is a bit clearer if you write it using joins instead of the old pre-1992 syntax:

```
select  L.Name
from    Manager M
join    Relation R 
on      R.PrimaryId = M.Id
join    Lead L
on      R.SecondaryId = L.Id
where   M.Id = 'M101'
```

You can add two new `left join`s to show the trainees per manager:

```
select  L.Name as lead
,       R.Name as trainee
from    Relation ML
join    Lead L
on      ML.SecondaryId = L.Id
left join
        Relation LT
on      LT.PrimaryId = L.Id
left join
        Trainee T
on      LT.SecondaryId = T.Id
where   ML.PrimaryId = 'M101'
```

Comment: I ned the query to return two columns Lead name and Trainee name.

Comment: Added a query that does that. It only makes sense if there's no more than one trainee and no more than one lead per manager.

Comment: Yes , with this criteria the query works , but at an instance, a manager can have a lead without a trainee. The query gives wrong results for this criteria.

Comment: Aah, so the trainee is related to the lead, not the manager, I've updated the query.